# How many Healing Surges to start with?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system

On "The Legend of Drizzt" Page 4 of the rule book under "To Start Playing:" it says:

> Unless the adventure says otherwise, place the Start tile in the center of the table and place **two Healing Surge tokens beside it. These are the group's surges for this adventure.**

And it also says:

> Check the "Starting Awards" section of the adventure's setup section **to see how many Healing Surge tokens the Heroes start with**, as well as any starting Treasure cards.

So does this mean that 2 Healing Surges is the default and any in the Starting Awards section *overwrites* this or are the Starting Award Healing Surges *in addition* to the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the adventure specifies how many Healing Surge tokens you start with, that's how many you start with.** (it overrides the default two instead of adding)

> Unless the adventure says otherwise … place two Healing Surge tokens.

If the adventure says to place three Healing Surge tokens, then "the adventure says otherwise" so you don't follow the default instruction. You'd just have three.

Comment: Thanks, this was a bit confusing to me and 4 seemed like it'd be way too easy.